# Display search result as you type in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, search

I have a textbox and a literal control on my page. Whenever a user enters search text in the textbox, the HTML code with the result gets generated behind the code and gets added to the literal control.

So, now I am trying to display search result as the user types in the textbox.

Can anyone tell me how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look no further than jQuery UI's [autocomplete for remote data sources](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote).

For a textbox like..

```
<input id="birds" />
```

You would need to do something like..

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({ source: "search.php" });
```

The rest is all just tweaking according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to emulate Google behavior.

In this case you need to send ajax request every time when user typed new symbol in your text and substitute html. But you will need change your `Literal` control to some 'div' or `Panel` because you can't find `Literal` control via Javascript. It's just substituted by a html content

ex:

```
$('#searchbox').keypress(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "search.html",
      data: { q: $('#searchbox').val() },
      cache: true,
      success: function(html){
        $("#results").html(html);
      }
    });
});
```

It's just a sample and probably needs some corrections. But idea in it.

**Handling JSON data** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Comment: i can change the literal to something else. i just need to know how i can do that.

Comment: the whole reason i used literal was because i am getting a list of custom object e.g. (employee object which has empID, empName, empAddress). I loop through the list and add the necessary fields from the object and create html and in literal. Can javascript get the return list of object, loop through the list and display the result.

Comment: use instead of literal `<div id="results"></div>` for example. On the server side pre-load html content there, on on client side use approach from the sample.

Comment: Yes, you can use JSON to transfer your objects to the client side and iterate through it using jQuery. Check the second sample

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is JQuery Autocomplete.  You can find it [HERE.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)